# Python Scrapy - Trying to use pagination that is "#" and redirects me to same page

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm building a **scraper** for [this page](https://www.ponts.org/fr/annuaire/recherche?result=1&annuaire_mode=standard&annuaire_as_no=&keyword=&PersonneNom=&PersonnePrenom=&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2023&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2022&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2021&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2020&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2019&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2018&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2017&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2016&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2015&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2014&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2013&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2012&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2011&DiplomePromo%5B%5D=2010)
I want to follow to next page after making first page work and after setting auto throttle and download speed to be gentle and I tried using:

```py
next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="global-pagination"]/a[@class="next"]/@href').get()
if next_page is not None:
    yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Problem is that href in that class is # and basically it opens same page again. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at your browser developer tool you will see when you go to other pages data loads from [loadresult](https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult). furthermore by searching in **Form Data** you'll see there is a field named `page` have a value of the page you requested which you can request any other page by changing it in your formdata in `FormRequest`.
[image]

```py
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

FormRequst(url=url, formdata=formdata={'page': <page number>}, callback=<parse method>)
```

Comment: So how do I use it exactly? I create variable say current_page = 1 and in for loop iterating through page xpaths to get data I give that variable +=1 and then finally in FormRequest {'page': current_page} ? I can't find any Form Data in loadresult network tools, for base site FormData shows just a long nick that never changes - its basicly made of ticked search options for given years.

Comment: I updated the answer and added a screenshot. you can overwrite `start_request` method and put the loop in it.

Comment: What do I put in as url in yielded FormRequest? what I have in start_urls?  this is what I got so far https://paste.tortoisecommunity.com/ogebogosap.py does it seem sensible or there are some obvious errors there?

Comment: you dont need `start_urls` when you override `start_request` put https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult as url

Comment: I got it like that https://paste.tortoisecommunity.com/hapijivihu.py but it doesn't do anything: it prints [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult> (referer: None) and closes spider also I don't quite understand how using that url will keep filter choices for that page?

Comment: `yield FormRequest(url=url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse)`

Comment: Well thanks for pointing me in somewhat bright direction but I don't really know what you're saying. I'd probably help me if you edited my script to show me what I'm missing because as it stands i don't quite comprehend whats what.

Comment: The last line of `start_request` method should be like previous comment

Comment: 2020-09-16 02:17:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.ponts.org/annuaire/ajax/loadresult> (referer: None)
2020-09-16 02:17:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
and no output still

Comment: Output comes from your parse method, your post request seems fine so you have to test you XPath and data you want to get in shell at first. Try to view the page in shell and check if it's what you want.

Comment: I got answer somewhere else that scrapy gets nothing from that because it can't handle javascript on that site. I have to use splash or selenium to get it done. You have any experience with that? P.S Xpaths are fine, i've been getting data from them when I connected to base url before (not loadresult one).